# Role based authorization in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am running jenkins by extracting the jenkins.war file.I have installed role based authorization strategy plugin for jenkins security.I have created a admin who has full access to jenkins.And I have created users who have access to only their projects.But when I close the command prompt and run jenkins.war again and login as admin I find admin does not having any privilages and the users i have created does not have any access to the privilages.What might be the problem.Is there something I am doing wrong.Please help